# \16x\n turns the Linux's terminal on a mess

Tags: c++, linux

When I run the code below on a Linux's terminal, the terminal turns on a mess.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("\16x\n");

    return 0;
}
```

For the sake of curiosity, can someone explain me what is happening here? I know the problem is in \16x, but I don't know why it happens.

Comment: I think it has something to do with escape sequences, but I cannot explain what really happens. I just know issuing the `reset` command should bring your terminal back to normal mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\16` is the ASCII octal code for Shift Out. In modern terminals, it makes something like this happen (image from Wikipedia):
[image: Borked terminal]
This ASCII code used to be used for various manufacturer specific uses around switching encodings, languages, and so on.

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_Out_and_Shift_In_characters) for more details on what they used to do.